# Can a Ukranian citizen with a C1D visa transit two stops within the USA?

Tags: visas, usa, transit-visas, ukrainian-citizens

I have Ukrainian citizenship and am in Peru. I wish to transit the USA while flying from Peru to Ukraine. I have flights from Lima, Peru to Fort Lauderdale, Florida, USA, from Fort Lauderdale to New York, New York to Kiev, then Kiev to Lvov, Ukraine. I have a C1D transit visa.

My question is: Can I do 2 transit stops in the USA? Will I be able to make those flights with my visa?

I'm arriving in Fort Lauderdale on Jan 24 at 6 AM. I will leave the USA on Jan 25 at 12.30 AM.

I know I can make this trip if all flights are in one day. In this case, does it mean one day or 24 hours?

Comment: Although you don't say when you depart Fort Lauderdale and arrive in New York, it looks as though your travel is continuous and, as @pnuts provides, 'reasonably expeditous'. It shouldn't be a problem that your onward flight from NY is just after midnight, so that you leave the country on the 25th.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. And transit admissions to the US usually have a maximum stay of 29 days.

Answer (score 10):

There is no "1 day" limit, travel should be 'reasonably expeditious':

> Transit (C) visas are nonimmigrant visas for persons traveling in immediate and continuous transit through the United States en route to another country, with few exceptions. Immediate and continuous transit is defined as a reasonably expeditious departure of the traveler in the normal course of travel as the elements permit and assumes a prearranged itinerary without any unreasonable layover privileges. If the traveler seeks layover privileges for purposes other than for transit through the United States, such as to visit friends or engage in sightseeing, the traveler will have to qualify for the type of visa required for that purpose.

[Bureau of Consular Affairs, U.S. Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/transit.html)

Comment: Right. What they are looking for are people who say "oops, I have a one week layover, better make the best of it and spend a few days at Disney World, and maybe the beach, heh heh."